# Django Rest Framework: How to custom serializer.data's value?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I call `serializer.data`, ManyToManyField will be displayed as list of ids,

but I want it to show `tags`'s names instead of ids.

models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)


class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from stories.models import Story, Tag


class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name',)


class StorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ('title', 'tags')

    def is_valid(self, raise_exception=False):
        self.initial_data['tags'] = self.get_tags_ids(self.initial_data['tags'])
        return super().is_valid(raise_exception)

    def get_tags_ids(self, tags):
        tags_ids = []
        for tag in tags:
            tag, _ = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)
            tags_ids.append(tag.id)

        return tags_ids
```

then in shell

```
In [1]: from stories.serializers import StorySerializer                         

In [2]: StorySerializer()                                                       
Out[2]: 
StorySerializer():
    title = CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_empty=False, many=True, queryset=Tag.objects.all())

In [3]: TEST_DATA = { 
...:     'title': 'A story', 
...:     'tags': ['horror', 'action'], 
...: }                                                                       

In [4]: ser = StorySerializer(data=TEST_DATA)                                     

In [5]: ser.is_valid()                                                            
Out[5]: True

In [6]: ser.data                                                                  
Out[6]: {'title': 'A story', 'tags': [1, 2]}
```

How to let `ser.data` return `{'title': 'A story', 'tags': ['horror', 'action']}` instead?

Comment: have you read [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)? or [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StringRelatedField` [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)

In your model add this `method`

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)

    def __str__(self) :  # <- This Method in Tag Model
        return self.name
```

Serializer.py

```
class StorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True) # <- This line
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ('title', 'tags')
```

There is another way also to do it - **[Nested Serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)**

Serializer.py

```
class TagsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): # <- This Serializer
    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = ('name',)

class StorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True) # <- This line
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ('title', 'tags')
```

Comment: another option is use [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield), the cons is that you don't need change anything except in the `StorySerializer` class.  add `tags = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', source='tags',read_only=True)`, and it works.